# Build a flutter real time listview without using Firebase

Tags: database, flutter

I been playing a round with flutter and dart, while you might be productive at a point you might get confused as well. My goal is to build a list view from an api, once the api changes one if its fields say. The url field, it automatically updats the list view.

This alll can be done by using firebase plugin but what if not to use fire base but a self hosted json api'couchdb / loopback.io'.
I am lost between futures and streams and redux. So please provide me with an example and keep it simple.

edite:01; providing code and use case;

below is my app. it can fetch images from self hosted api as mentioned realier 'couchdb / loopback.io', each time button clicked, the click part can be ignored, what i aim for is to have the list automatically update if new 'post' fired tot he api say by postman.
now; i been reading on streams redux i just can not wrap my head arround it , could be the language of the documentation of the presumed knowledge the reader should have, thats why i asked for an example so i can understand it well.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'src/app.dart';
    void main(){
      runApp(App());
    }


    class ImageModel {

      int id;
      String name;
      String url;


      ImageModel.fromJson(parsedJson){
        id = parsedJson['id'];
        name = parsedJson['name'];
        url = parsedJson['url'];

      }


    }



    //import
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' show get; //import for making http requests
    import 'models/image_model.dart'; //import model
    import 'dart:convert'; //convert json
    import 'widgets/image_list.dart'; //import image widget



    class App extends StatefulWidget{

      createState() {
        return AppState();
      }

    }


    // create class
    class AppState extends State<App> {

      int counter = 0;
      List<ImageModel> images = [];


      void fetchImage() async{

        counter++;
       var response = await get('http://192.168.1.66:3000/api/images/$counter');
       var imageModel = ImageModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

       setState(() {
         images.add(imageModel);
       });


      }


      Widget build(context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: ImageList(images),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: fetchImage,


              child: Icon(Icons.add),

            ),
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Title'),

            ),

          ),
        );
      }


    }

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import '../models/image_model.dart';


    class ImageList extends StatelessWidget {

      final List<ImageModel> images;

      ImageList(this.images);


      Widget build(context) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: images.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,int index){

            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Image.network(images[index].url),

            );

          },
        );
      }

    }
```

Comment: The only difference between Firebase and most other API is how you get new information... Firebase sends notifications to you, and otherwise you use a periodic loop of the same query... Where exactly are you stuck implementing that?

Comment: @ cricket_007 check my edit, and advice please.

Comment: If you're able to make one request, you can schedule it to repeat, giving the illusion of "realtime" updates https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html

Comment: Alternatively, you could look at alternative database solutions such as RethinkDB, Couchbase Sync, or Parse Server that'll provide you with similar APIs to Firebase

Comment: Best answer so far. Is there best time frame for the timer? Do you think any of this can be done with dart? https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Synchronization.html

Comment: As mentioned there, Loopback is only for Javascript, so you'd have to switch to React Native or Ionic, probably, to use that. I would put a timer on at least 2 second loop, depending on how frequently data is actually changing, how long the query takes in general (don't execute another query before you rendered old results), and how much load repetitive queries take on the database

Comment: @cricket_007 been able to call rest api with timer, but the Listview blinks 2 to 3 times each time timer called, eventually app crash "too many files open..etc"

Comment: That might mean your timer is too frequent, but I'm not familiar with Flutter to really know the solution there

Answer (score 2):

One could use [Dart WebSockets](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/websockets) to accomplish the task; Firebase is in principle nothing else - a custom WSS-API could even be backed by an actual SQL server. A broad question always will result in a broad answer.

Comment: @s.u and how shall client-side code be of relevance for an API? this does not exactly improve the quality of the question; better come back once you're stuck with an actual problem during the implementation and do have an actual question concerning it.

Comment: i am lost and can not wrap my head around it. Have watched all youtube videos from Tensor to google io. Each time i read or play videos i get more stuck . You do not want to example me you are totally fine sure somebody else will help. You could be very good at what you do but do not order people to go and comeback. I am here because i can not do more . Seeking help.

Comment: @s.u you've asked for a substitute for Firebase and I've provided a valid one, according the the given environment. and YouTube won't teach you programming, only reading and writing code helps there; and if it should get "too much"... just gain some distance to the problem and look another time at it again. also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (this does influence the outcome of a question much).

Comment: @s.u https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-samples/tree/master/html5/web/websockets/basics ...

Comment: Firebase is actually built over MongoDB (or a form of it), not RDBMS/SQL

Comment: Anyway, how do "websockets" help a mobile app? Are they even possible in Flutter?

Comment: @cricket_007 this is exactly why I've noticed, that one could even use a SQL server (as noSQL may impose a dis-advance eg. when requiring domain aggregate functions); and if Dart supports the server, it is quite likely that Flutter supports the client (the Firebase client is also just a WS client). see https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/web-sockets/ ...the server is nevertheless just HTTP during the initial request, which then upgrades the connection from half-duplex HTTP to full-duplex WS; eg. in order to be able to push notifications to clients, without having them to request updates.

Comment: so i get clear, are you guys suggesting i give firebase plugin a try with my non firebase api? in web sockets should i just replace this var and `   ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');
' with my api endpoint and get the output?

Comment: @s.u despite the Firebase plugin implements a web-socket client, you cannot use it to connect other WS endpoints, but the predefined ones. there first one link I've provided is a simple server and the second is the corresponding client (and alike that, you could access your own WS API even on the local network). when starting off simple, it would also be a good practice, in order to actually learn programming.

Comment: @MartinZeitler  been able to call rest api with timer, but the Listview blinks 2 to 3 times each time timer called, eventually app crash "too many files open..etc"

Answer (score -3):

You can use firestore and reference the data in flutter with StreamBuilder widgets. Any time something changes in the firestore collection, the streams listens to the change and rebuild the ui

[You can watch it in action in this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4yLzYwy_4g)

Comment: i do not use firebase! will i be able to use firestore without using firebase?

Comment: @s.u Mm nope, I don't think so